# Alinear elementos en 2 columnas dentro de un div

Tags: css, css3

¿Es posible alinear diferentes `article`s dentro de un `div`, tocando el CSS del `div`? También podría tocar el CSS referente a los `article`, pero estos cargan según las publicaciones.

Éste es mi código:

```css
.izq{
  float: left;
 margin-left: 0px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 48%;
  clear: both;
 margin-left: 0;
  border: 1px solid;
}
.der{
  float: right;
 margin-right: 2.564102564102564%;
  width: 48%;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="cotainer">
  <article class="izq">art1</article>
  <article class="der">art2<p>contiene 1 parrafo</article>
  <article class="izq">art3 mas texto <p> otra parrafo <p> otro parrafo</article>
  <article class="der">art4<br> mas texto<br> mas texto</article>
  <article class="izq">art5 <p> un par de parrafos </article>
  <article class="der">art6 <p> articulo 6 contiene <p> 4 parrafos en total<p> contando este</article>
</div>
```

Actualmente se ve algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Mi intención es cuadrar cada "article" y dejarlo parejo de esta forma:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Observad la cuadrícula en el segundo caso, mientras que actualmente la línea horizontal de elementos parejos no está alineada.

Aquí lo que hice fue jugar con el elemento `height` del `article`, pero esta propiedad solo actua si se introduce la cantidad del height en px, y mi intención es que sea más "responsive".

Comment: Lo que necesitas es usar flexbox. Pero para poder ayudarte y aplicarlo mejor a tu caso, deberías compartir tu código en la propia pregunta (crea un [mcve]); de lo contrario las respuestas que vas a recibir van a ser genéricas. Un enlace a tu sitio web no es suficiente porque cuando soluciones el problema, se dejará de ver y esta pregunta dejará de tener sentido.

Comment: He creado este pequeño codigo con una estrucutura muy similar a la que uso, gracias y llevas razón, debería haberlo publicado antes:
http://cssdeck.com/labs/edoz0ptl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo haciendo una grilla con Flexbox. Por defecto, un elemento `flex` cuya dirección es `row` (horizontal) *estira* a sus hijos verticalmente, de modo que todos ocupan el mismo alto.

Además preferencia, dale un alto fijo a las imágenes y un ancho a las cajas de acuerdo a la resolución en la que se muestren. Por ejemplo, en móbiles las imágenes podría ser 200px de alto, en tablets, 250px, en laptops, 300px, etc. Así mismo, las cajas pueden tener un ancho inicial del 80% de la pantalla y conforme vaya creciendo la resolución, se reduce su ancho para que se vayan mostrando horionalmente. Esto lo puedes hacer fácilmente mediante media queries.

**Ejemplo**

Mira el ejemplo en varias resoluciones para ver como cambian su ancho.

```css
.posts {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 20px;
}

.post {
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .25), 0 -1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 12px 5px;
  width: 80%;
}

.post figure {
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.post figure img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.post pre {
  color: #555;
  font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 22px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0 10px;
  text-align: justify;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  max-width: 100%;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 700px) {
  .posts {
    justify-content: space-between;
   }
   
  .post {
    width: 45%;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .posts {
    justify-content: space-between;
   }
   
  .post {
    width: 30%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="posts">
    <article class="post">
      <figure>
        <img src="http://travelkids.es/Uploads/ImageGalleryModuleDto/ORLANDO.jpg" alt="">
      </figure>
      <pre>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facilis, tempora ad omnis harum excepturi neque illo. Deserunt suscipit nesciunt consequatur ullam, facere molestiae quo sequi. Officiis voluptate eos ipsa quod!</pre>
    </article>
    <article class="post">
      <figure>
        <img src="http://travelchannel.sndimg.com/content/dam/images/travel/fullset/2014/12/3/top-california-beach-getaways-venice-beach.jpg.rend.tccom.1280.960.jpeg" alt="">
      </figure>
      <pre>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cumque temporibus ea necessitatibus consectetur animi, fuga minima deserunt vero placeat quas molestias accusantium reiciendis consequatur amet facilis consequuntur velit, neque omnis!</pre>
    </article>
    <article class="post">
      <figure>
        <img src="http://www.leannemoore.ie/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/london.jpg" alt="">
      </figure>
      <pre>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quidem distinctio vitae eaque voluptatem, ratione aspernatur? Quidem laboriosam voluptate nam perferendis praesentium ut delectus, asperiores labore sed optio reprehenderit illo neque.</pre>
    </article>
    <article class="post">
      <figure>
        <img src="http://sitiosturisticos.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/Madrid.jpg" alt="">
      </figure>
      <pre>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tenetur ad, voluptates aut, in nam veritatis. Tempore tenetur est doloremque ratione consectetur perferendis, voluptate odit beatae recusandae in id blanditiis odio?</pre>
    </article>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```